# Should the election pages link to the meta profile instead?

Tags: feature-request, election

Currently, [election pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/election) show reputation and badge counts for the main site's profile and link to the main site's profile page. I don't think this is a good idea.

> Our general criteria for moderators is as follows:
>
> - patient and fair
> - leads by example
> - shows respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words
> - open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track and resolve (hopefully) uncommon disputes and exceptions

Those qualities can only really be judged when you see a user's participation on the meta site. You don't need patience and fairness to be a top user on a site, even though it helps; you don't need competence and clarity to be a top moderator on a site, even though it helps.

Comment: I don't think the election pages should show the meta profile *instead of* the main profile. I think it'd be more useful to simply see **both**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of those qualities to be active on either site, but the user's activity tab on the parent site will show you if they're patient, fair, show respect, etc. I would probably check both profiles, but the parent site is definitely not unimportant

Comment: There's a problem with this, however. The main profile page does _not_ link to the same user's meta profile -- to jump from one to the other you'd have to manually prepend "meta." to the URL (or go to Meta, click Users, search for the user's name and click on the relevant result). In short, it's unlikely to happen.

Comment: @radp Oh, prepending `meta.` is a good way to do it; I normally do the lengthy second way you mentioned :). It seems like parent profiles should link to meta ones; I'm not sure why they didn't do it that way